# Full text seach in Doctrine using query builder with no result hits

Tags: sql-server, doctrine, full-text-search, query-builder, formsof

##### Specs:

- Symfony v5.3.16
- SQL Server 2017
- Doctrine Bundle v2.4.4
- Doctrine ORM v2.9.6

I've got a problem with full text search for SQL Server using Doctrine's query builder. I'm trying to use it with predicate 'FORMSOF' but as a result I get 0 hits from query.

I approached it in couple ways like:

```
$qb->where("CONTAINS(es.name, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, :searchParam)')");
```

or

```
$formsof = new Func('FORMSOF', ['INFLECTIONAL', $searchParam]);
$containsFunc = new Func('CONTAINS', ['es.name', "'$formsof'"]);
$qb->add('where', $containsFunc);
```

I've also tried using DQL Custom Functions but with not results however it wasn't properly setup for sure because I was wondering if I should make 2 custom functions because of *CONTAINS* and *FORMSOF* or maybe one for *CONTAINS* or just *FORMSOF*?

The weird part is that native SQL query directly on the database works:

```
SELECT name
FROM cms_eservice ce
WHERE CONTAINS (name, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, queryWord)');
```

And even native SQL using Doctrine however query builder approach does not.

And I want to stick with query builder because it's big query so it's easier to maintain that way.

My best shot is that 'FORMSOF' part is taken literally as a string by query builder. Just my assumption.

Comment: Are you able to capture the exact query sent to SQL Server using Symfony, SQL Profiler or Extended Events? I suspect it's treating `:searchParam` as a regular input parameter and quoting the search term instead of leaving it "in the clear" like your `queryWord` example does.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried to hardcode the input instead of using input parameter to just take it out of an equation. I will try to capture raw sql query. Thanks!